# Functional Interface Method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I am new to java 8 and trying this.
i have an interface

```
public interface CurrencyRateDao{
    Double getCurrencyRate(String srcCur,String tarCur, int month);
}
```

Accessing using it this way :

```
CurrencyRateDao currencyRateDao = new CurrencyRateDaoImpl();
Double rate = ('USD','INR',1) -> currencyRateDao::getCurrencyRate;
```

Giving an error:

> target type of this expression must be a functional interface.

Please suggest what is wrong with above code

Answer (score 3):

You simply need

```
Double rate = currencyRateDao.getCurrencyRate("USD", "INR", 1);
```

If you were to represent the interface as a lambda, it would look like :

```
CurrencyRateDao currencyRateDao = (srcCur, tarCur, month) -> Double.MAX_VALUE;
// accepts three arguments and returns a Double value
```